# For some reason typoscript is not creating symlink to my Public folder

Tags: typo3, symlink, typoscript

After i added my typoscript page logic like the following:

```
config {
    contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
}
page = PAGE

-- some code ---

page.includeJSFooter {
    jquery = https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
    bootstrap = https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

    typed = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/lib/typed/typed.min.js
    easing = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/lib/easing/easing.min.js
    waypoints = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js
    owlcarousel = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js
    isotope = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js
    lightbox = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js
    jqBootstrapValidation = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.min.js
    contact = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/mail/contact.js
    main = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/js/main.js
}
page.shortcutIcon = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Public/icons/reading.ico
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Private/Template/Default.html
        layoutRootPath = EXT:mywebsite/Resources/Private/Layout
    }
}
-- some code ---
```

i figured out that my symlink in public/_assets Folder has not been created

I added the necessary symlink to the folder, and things worked, but I'm still wondering why my symlink wasn't generated automatically
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zr7a.png)

what i checked

-I changed the permissions of 'public/_assets' to 777 to ensure that privilege issues were not the cause.

-I checked

```
AddType application/javascript   js
```

in my .htaccess file and it was there

am using Composer version "12.4.8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to mention if you have a composer or a non-composer mode installation and if you changed the folder structure.

If you have a composer installation, normally the missing symlinks should be created if you run:

```bash
composer dump-autoload
# or
composer install
```

For a non-composer installation, there should be no "assets symlink" logic. That happens if you used some magic constants to change the folder structure, so that some code paths thinks they are in composer-mode and other not.

Comment: I noted that I'm using 'Composer version 12.4.8' at the end of my description, and yes, the solution was helpful. I appreciate that.